# Write on textbox in a thread (TASK) in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio, task

I have a program (In WPF Application) which receive by a thread info from COM port. 
Here's part from that:

```
static async Task ReceiveData(SerialPort port)
    {
       try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);  // Time for read works
                await port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 55);  //Wait recive data from Serial Port

                textBox.AppendText("Test");
            }           
    }
```

The problem occurs because it can be write in the text box just in this task.
I have a lot of others textBox outside and works just fine.
The error who show is:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'MainWindow.textBox'

If I change the task for public the error disappears but when I build the program the text don't appear on the box.

I know the message it's about reference but it seems this part is OK, I think it's something about turn the textBox in public access.

I change the code just for:

```
async Task ReceiveData(SerialPort port)
```

And the following error appears on output:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll

And the error is: ""The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.""

---------- SOLVED BY @BrandonKramer ----------
Using:

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => textBox.AppendText("Test")));
```

Comment: Never use Thread.Sleep in asynchronous code, it defeats the whole point.  If you need to delay for some reason, use await Task.Delay() instead.

Comment: The error you are getting is telling you, that you cannot access instance members from a static method.  static means the method is shared across all instances of the class, but textBox is a property or field that is specific to a given object.

Comment: If you change static async Task ReceiveData() to just async Task ReceiveData() then that error will go away.

Comment: @BrandonKramer I change and occurs the samething, I noticed now the exception that occurs on output, I'm editing this post.

Comment: You also cannot modify controls (like a TextBox) from a thread other then the one they were created on.

Comment: Can you see the error message associated with the InvalidOperationException?

Comment: @BrandonKramer The error is: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is because UI elements, such as a TextBox, can only be modified from the UI thread.

In order to fix this issue, change:

```
textBox.AppendText("Test");
```

to

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => textBox.AppendText("Test")));
```

This will cause `textBox.AppendText("Test");` to be executed on the UI thread, rather then the background thread that your task is executing on.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Now it's woking! There's a short way to do this? Imagine this long structure in all my code :(

Comment: It doesn't get any shorter then this, sorry.

Comment: No problem! Thank you again! @BrandonKramer